# Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AddReference'?

Tags: python, .net, clr, ironpython, python.net

Am trying to use clr.AddReference and clr.AddReferenceToFile to import an assembly, but python(2.7) keeps making this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    clr.AddReference("UnityEngine")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AddReference'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 49):

Once I met this issue.
There is a package named **clr** while the **pythonnet** package's alias is also **clr**.
So I removed **clr** by "`pip uninstall clr`" and then installed **pythonnet** by '`pip install pythonnet`'.
Finally, everything works well.

Comment: Does pythonnet work on Linux systems? I get an error when installing: `error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized`

Comment: I had this problem to and can confirm that this answer works.

Answer (score 8):

You must be using the wrong 'clr' module.
remove it

```
pip uninstall clr
```

And then install pythonnet

```
pip install pythonnet
```

Answer (score 4):

run the code

```
import clr
dir(clr)
```

if the reasult is as ['StyleBuilder', '**builtins**', '**cached**',....]
then the problem is your IDE is installing the WRONG Clr module

Comment: So whats the correct version to download in that case? Any idea

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having normal clr installed, the mistake I made was the little script I was using to test python.net was named pythonnet.py. So when python.net was trying to load itself, it found my script instead and problems ensued. If you get this specific error:

```
partially initialized module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
```

That could be why.