# Why can I access this API from IronPython but not Python.NET?

Tags: ironpython, python.net

I’m working on a project that uses the [Tekla EPM Open API](https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-epm/documentation/tekla-epm-open-api-how-it-works).

I have no difficulty interfacing with it using IronPython, but have had less luck using Python.NET, which I would prefer for its greater compatibility with other modules.

The API documentation states:

> There is only one function in the dll file that can be called. The c-style declaration is:
>
> ```
> char *_FabSuiteXML( char * );
> ```

Accordingly, the following (obfuscated) code works as expected in IronPython (3.4.0a1, .NETFramework v4.6 on .NET Framework 4.8.4360.0 (64-bit) on win32):

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append('[…]\\Tekla\\Tekla EPM')
clr.AddReference("FabSuiteAPI")
import FabSuite

interface = FabSuite.FabSuiteAPI.FabSuiteAPI()

connection_string = '''
<FabSuiteXMLRequest>
<Connect>
<IPAddress>XXX.XXX.X.XX</IPAddress>
<PortNumber>XXX</PortNumber>
<Username>XXXXXX</Username>
</Connect>
</FabSuiteXMLRequest>'''

connection_response = interface.FabSuiteXML(connection_string)

print(interface)
#Yields: <FabSuite.FabSuiteAPI.FabSuiteAPI object at 0x000000000000002B [FabSuite.FabSuiteAPI.FabSuiteAPI]>

print(connection_response)
#Yields:
"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<FabSuiteXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.fabsuite.com/xml/fabsuite-xml-response-v0108.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Lang>en</Lang>
  <Connect>
    <Successful>1</Successful>
    <FabSuiteMajorVersion>XXXX</FabSuiteMajorVersion>
    <FabSuiteMinorVersion>XXXX</FabSuiteMinorVersion>
  </Connect>
"""
```

However, in (ordinary) python (3.9.5) using Python.NET, I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[…]\overflow_question_code1.py", line 15, in <module>
    connection_response = interface.FabSuiteXML(connection_string)
AttributeError: 'FabSuiteAPI' object has no attribute 'FabSuiteXML'
```

And indeed, python’s help() shows only those methods inherited from System.Object for the FabSuiteAPI object.

Any idea why the key method is not available in Python.NET?

Related, unhelpful Question:
[Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AddReference'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47913079/16298672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python.NET 2.5 does not support COM interop. Here's the [tracking issue](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/260).

There's a long worded [workaround using .NET reflection](https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/ec559b5af41060c5ac318f7f59d8b415).

BTW, if COM interop is the reason for using Python.NET you might in fact be better with a native Python COM client library like [`win32com`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html)

Comment: win32com is indeed what I should have been using in the first place, thank you:
```
import win32com.client
interface = win32com.client.Dispatch("FabSuite.FabSuiteAPI.FabSuiteAPI")
connection_response = interface.FabSuiteXML(connection_string)
```

Comment: (The markdown for "in-line code snippets is *immediate enclosure in `\`` backticks*, no triple (code block fence - I prefer `~~~`) or whitespace around.)