# Unable to install pythonnet clr module by uninstalling clr and re-installing clr

Tags: python, clr, python.net

I am trying to import clr and receive the following error:

`AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'`

I have tried to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913079/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-addreference), where I uninstalled both pythonnet and clr, and then install pythonnet and then clr.

However, I still get the same error.

I'm using spyder 5.4.1 (on a virtual Windows machine).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This happened to me. There was a CLR.py file that my env (PyCharm virtual env) was holding on to. Once I deleted that it was good to go

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and came across your post (and also your link).
The solution for me in spyder was to DIABLE the "User Module Option" (UMR) option under:

> Preferences --> Python Interpreter --> UMR

It seems that spyder thinks it has to reload the wrong (and previously uninstalled) clr package when using the "rufile" command (which you do by hitting F5 to launch your script).
I hope it helps!